# Node.js net socket memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, v8

I have [this script](https://gist.github.com/danypype/a2c46da944a0eeb96b7f).

```
var net = require("net")
,   heapdump = require("heapdump");
 
function onConnection (client) {
  client.on("data", function (data) {
    client.end();
  });
};
 
function onListen () {
  var socket = net.connect({host: "127.0.0.1", port: 3000});
 
  socket.bigBuffer = new Buffer(50000000); //50MB Buffer
 
  heapdump.writeSnapshot(__dirname + "/initial.heapsnapshot", function writeInitialSnapshot () {
    console.log("Wrote initial heap snapshot");
    socket.write("data");
  });
 
  socket.on("close", function () {
    writeEndSnapshot();
  });
};
 
function writeEndSnapshot () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Running GC");
    gc();
 
    heapdump.writeSnapshot(__dirname + "/final.heapsnapshot", function writeFinalSnapshot () {
      console.log("Wrote final heap snapshot");
    });
  }, 1000);
};
 
net.createServer(onConnection).listen(3000, onListen);
```

What **test.js** does is pretty straight forward:

It creates a **net** server, which closes the clients right after receiving any data, and binds it to the port *3000* in *localhost*. When the server listens, the `onListen` function is executed, which instantiates a `socket` that connects to the server, and then takes a heap snapshot (please notice that in the line *13* we set a 50MB `bigBuffer` to the socket, this is just to easily locate it in the heap snapshot)

Right after taking the initial snapshot, the `sockets` writes some data to the server and gets ended, this is when the `writeEndSnapshot` function gets executed, which waits for the next tick, forces a GC (garbage collection) cycle, and then takes a final heap snapshot.

It seemed pretty clear for me that by the time the final snapshot is taken, the socket should have been disposed, and therefore, garbage-collected. However, this is not what I'm seeing in the Google Chrome's profiler when I load the snapshots.

### Initial heap snapshot

[image]

### Final heap snapshot

[image]

As you can see in the final snapshot, `bigBuffer` is still held by the `socket`. I have no idea why the `socket` is still alive. All I can see in the retainers tree after `socket` is `owner in TCP @27447`. Do you think this might be a node's bug?

I'd really appreciate any help to understand what's going on.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it possible that the underlying OS is still finishing the networking (sending data, waiting for TCP ACK from server, closing the socket, etc...) and thus everything related to the socket isn't quite yet available for GC internally when you assume it is.  Remember that networking is not a synchronous task at the OS level.  It takes time.  I'd suggest taking your final snapshot some number of seconds later after calling `gc()` again.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's why I'm waiting for the socket's "end" event to trigger the GC.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the "end" event means everything is done on the socket?  Also, where do you close the socket?

Comment: @jfriend00 I set a large timeout (10 seconds) before taking the last snapshot, and I can still see `socket` in the heap.

Comment: Where do you close the socket before taking the last snapshot?

Comment: I close it in the server side, line 6 of the `onConnection` function. It get's closed after writing data to the server on line 17.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62224/discussion-between-danypype-and-jfriend00).

Comment: I don't see a close after writing the data on line 17.  Sorry, but I don't know this library you're using so I don't know what each method does.  I see you closing on the receiving end, but not doing anything on the sending end so that end of the socket could still be alive internally.  Not sure if you have to clean up both ends or not.  Just trying to generate ideas.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for all your ideas. This is not a half-open socket, so it only requires to be ended in one end to be fully closed.
http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if there's only one client socket, this wont get garbage collected. Here's an updated script now with two sockets:

```
var net = require("net")
,   heapdump = require("heapdump");

function onConnection (client) {
  client.on("data", function (data) {
    client.end();
  });
};

function onListen () {
  var socket
  ,   sockets = []
  ,   closedSockets = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    socket = net.connect({host: "127.0.0.1", port: 3000});
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.bigBuffer = new Buffer(25000000); //25MB Buffer

    socket.on("close", function () {
      if (++closedSockets == sockets.length) {
        writeEndSnapshot();
      };
    });
  };

  heapdump.writeSnapshot(__dirname + "/initial.heapsnapshot", function () {
    console.log("Wrote initial heap snapshot");
    for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
      sockets[i].write("data");
    };
  });
};

function writeEndSnapshot () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Running GC");
    gc();

    heapdump.writeSnapshot(__dirname + "/final.heapsnapshot", function () {
      console.log("Wrote final heap snapshot");
    });
  }, 1000);
};

net.createServer(onConnection).listen(3000, onListen);
```

Everything works fine now. However, if you change the loop to instantiate just one socket, you'll see it keeps alive in the heap.